# Exec is not supported by the lxc driver: how to get around this?

Tags: docker, lxc, circleci

Using Docker on CoreOS, I have a script which calls:

```
docker exec ...
```

This works fine on CoreOS, but I also want to test it on [CircleCI](http://circleci.com). When I try to run that script on CircleCI, I get:

```
time="2015-06-22T01:14:51Z" level=fatal msg="Error response from daemon: Unsupported: Exec is not supported by the lxc driver" ./tests/run.sh returned exit code 1
```

[Here are the test results on CircleCI](https://circleci.com/gh/dcycleproject/dcyclebox/22).

I tried changing `docker exec` to `docker --exec-driver native exec`, however I am not entirely sure what a "driver" is, how to change it, or even if it's possible or desirable to do so.

What would be the best course of action around this error?

Comment: This is still an issue. If you absolutely need exec, you Travis CI supports it.

Answer (score 11):

An execution driver is what docker uses behind the scene to actually run the containers. There are two popular options: `lxc` (former default), `native` (current default)

Looks like CircleCI doesn't support `native` execution driver yet, which is why it lacks some of the features in docker. Apparently they are aware of this and have proposed a [workaround](https://circleci.com/docs/docker#docker-exec).

Comment: Yes, but that workaround doesn't work with docker 1.10 and later, so you can't use docker-compose with version 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with docker exec not working. I tried the work around that uses lxc-attach, but this did not work very well. I suspect I could have got it working with a bit more time.

In the end I made a custom bash script within the container that had all the commands I needed to run and used a normal "docker run" command.